Using puppeteer-real-browser with puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha
I was previously using puppeteer-extra and could easily solve captchas using the puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha library with the page.solveRecaptchas(); function. However, I had to switch to the puppeteer-real-browser library. Everything is going smoothly, but now that I'm using puppeteer-real-browser, I can't use puppeteer-extra plugins with this library, so I'm unable to solve captchas.
What kind of code should I implement to use both libraries at the same time?
Below is my code that I am having problems with:
import fs from 'fs';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import { connect } from 'puppeteer-real-browser';
import Stealth from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';
import anticaptcha from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha'
import axios from 'axios';

const start = async () => {
    try {
      
        connect({
          tf: false, 
          turnstile: true,
          args: [], 
          headless: 'auto', 
          customConfig: {},
          skipTarget: [],
          fingerprint: true,
          turnstile: true,
          connectOption: {}
          // proxy: {
          //     host: '<proxy-host>',
          //     port: '<proxy-port>',
          //     username: '<proxy-username>',
          //     password: '<proxy-password>'
          // }
      })
      .then(async response => {
        const { page, browser, setTarget } = response
            setTarget({ status: true })
    

        puppeteer.use(Stealth());
        puppeteer.use(anticaptcha({
            provider: {
                id: '2captcha',
                token: 'apikey',
            },
            visualFeedback: true,
            throwOnError: true
        }));

    })   


    //My codes....


    
} catch (error) {
  console.error('error:', error.message);
}
};


Please don't duplicate a paragraph to circumvent the question filters. Add more details.

If you don't mind, you can use browser extensions instead of puppeteer-extra plugin.
2captcha and capsolver.com services have their extensions and those are working well.
You can add timeout while extension solve the captcha.

The answer is actually a question from the comment's author.

Hello.
I think, you didn't understand me.
Now, in puppeteer-real-browser, puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha doesn't work because puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha package works on puppeteer-extra browser.
This code is their package.
import type { Browser, Page } from "puppeteer-core-patch";
import type { GhostCursor } from "ghost-cursor";

So, I have suggested capsolver and 2captcha extensions.
